# How can I extract image buffer from captureOutput (didDrop samplebuffer)?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

My application involves getting video frames from the camera and running CoreML on it. This will then get displayed on the view. To do this, I have an AVCaptureSession() that is hooked to a video output. The main processing of CoreML is being done in captureOutput(didOutput Samplebuffer). Each processing of the frame takes about 0.15 seconds, meaning that I WILL have some dropped frames.After CoreML process is done, I have an AVAssetWriter that append all these frames together and saves it within the phone directory.

THE main problem is however, that my use-case also requires the original video to be saved, and this video should have HIGH FPS and since I am only able to get the image frames only in captureOutput(didOutput), the video quality will be choppy.

I have tried the following:

1. The reason that I'm using AVAssetWriter is because it is given here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98113#300885 that it is NOT POSSIBLE to have both AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.
2. I have also tried extracting Image buffer from the captureOutput(didDrop) using guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return } but it is giving me nil. This is because sampleBuffer only contains metadata but not imagebuffer as explained here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1388468-captureoutput.

Here is some of my code:

```
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) { /* HOW DO I possibly extract an image buffer here from the dropped frames here? */ }


    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    let inputVideoImage = UIImage(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

    if self.isRecording{
        let sourceTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
        if let camera = self.videoWriterVideoInput, camera.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            videoWriterQueue.async() { 
                self.videoWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: sourceTime)
            }
        }else{
            print("AVAssetInput is not ready for more media data ... ")
        }
    }
    
   runCoreML()
}
```